# jinja2 groupby grouping a custom sorted list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I have the following issue with `groupby` function in jinja:

I have a list of Dicts, where one key inside each is `[Tech]:**some tech value**`

and I want to sort and group in a custom manner, let's say I have

```
tech_order = [tech2, tech5, tech1, tech3, tech4] #these values are arbitrary just for example
```

When I do this using python only

```
def custom_sort_list_dictated(Dict, Key, list_order):
    Dict = Dict.sort(key=lambda k:list_order.index(k[Key])) 
#Written as function because I pass it later in jinja2.Environment.globals.update()

custom_sort_list_dictated(My_list_of_dicts, 'Tech', tech_order) 
#This works and sorts my dictionaries correctly

for key, value in itertools.groupby(Anforderungen, key=itemgetter('Tech')):
            Val_list.append(list(value))    # Store group iterator as a list
            Key_list.append(key)
```

Using `itertools.groupby` in python will group my custom sorted dictionaries according to my `tech_order` list and group them conserving the order.

This however is not the case in jinja2, I have the following template:

```
{{ custom_sort_list_dictated(My_list_of_dicts, 'Tech', tech_order) or '' }}

{% for Tech, group_by_tech in My_list_of_dicts|groupby('Tech') %}
        {{ jinja_append_array(Val_Array, list(group_by_tech)) or '' }}
        {{ jinja_append_array(Key_Array, Tech) or '' }}
{% endfor %}
```

However `groupby` in jinja2 sorts my dictionaries back in alphabetical order, unlike `itertools.groupby` in python. Is there a way not to have this happen?

I know the issue is jinja2 `groupby` because just calling:

```
{% for Tech, group_by_tech in My_list_of_dicts|groupby('Tech') %}
        {{ Tech + " ~~ " }}
{% endfor %} #This prints my techs in alphabetical order which is not consistent with itertools.groupby
```

PS: `jinja_append_array` and `custom_sort_list_dictated` are passed from python to jinja using `jinja2.Environment.globals.update()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up making my own `groupby()` custom function and passing it into `inja2.Environment.globals.update()` as follows:

```
import jinja2
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter


def custom_jinja_groupby(Dict, Key_list, Val_list, group_filter, parse_filter):
    temp_array = []
    for key, value in itertools.groupby(Dict, key=itemgetter(group_filter)):
        Key_list.append(key)
        for content in value:
            Parse_Info_Dictionary(content, parse_filter) #another custom function as I needed to make some changes to my grouping
            temp_array.append(content)
        Val_list.append(temp_array)
        temp_array=[]

template_file_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('{}'.format(path_to_jinja_template_folder))
env = jinja2.Environment(loader = template_file_loader)
env.globals.update(custom_jinja_groupby = custom_jinja_groupby)
```

I can use this in my Jinja file as follows:

```
{{ custom_jinja_groupby(My_Dict_To_Group, Key_Array, Val_Array, 'group_by_This', 'Custom_function_at_This') or '' }}
```

Note the `or ''` is used because otherwise it will print None into your rendered file, this will have it print nothing and still perform the function changes. The goal is getting `Key_Array` and 'Val_Array' which are passed by reference I guesss inside the jinja file but this will pretty much keep your custom ordering after grouping. Hope this helps someone later on.